# Issue in FFmpegAndroid library when i compress video it convert video time into 1 or 2 second

Tags: ffmpeg

Used this dependencies:
 compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

I used blow code for video compress
   public static final String VIDEOCODEC = "-vcodec";
    public static final String AUDIOCODEC = "-acodec";

```
public static final String VIDEOBITSTREAMFILTER = "-vbsf";
public static final String AUDIOBITSTREAMFILTER = "-absf";

public static final String VERBOSITY = "-v";
public static final String FILE_INPUT = "-i";
public static final String SIZE = "-s";
public static final String FRAMERATE = "-r";
public static final String FORMAT = "-f";
public static final String BITRATE_VIDEO = "-b:v";

public static final String BITRATE_AUDIO = "-b:a";
public static final String CHANNELS_AUDIO = "-ac";
public static final String FREQ_AUDIO = "-ar";
```

String[] complexCommand = {"-y", FILE_INPUT, yourRealPath, SIZE, "480x360", FRAMERATE, "25", VIDEOCODEC, "mpeg4", BITRATE_VIDEO, "150k", BITRATE_AUDIO, "48000", CHANNELS_AUDIO, "2", FREQ_AUDIO, "22050", filePath};

```
/**
 * Executing ffmpeg binary
 */
private static String execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {


    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                Log.d(TAG, "progress : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting